# Hadoop - Directory Structure and Distributed Cache

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce, distributed-cache

Imagine the situation, that I have multiple jobs executing concurrently in a hadoop cluster. 
These jobs are using the Distributed Cache. Each of them use diferent files , but with the same name. (I am using the ToolInteface to distribute these files.)

I imagine that Distributed Cache is shared among jobs, so if i use the same name of file to all jobs, the files of distributed cache will be override. Am I right?

Comment: Maybe you want to read how the distributed cache is implemented, it will just copy the files to a job local directory. You can't share the distributed cache amonst jobs.

Comment: I know that it will copy the files to a local directory. So i understand, taht files with same names, but used in diferent jobs will not be overriden? Each job has a "private" directory", with the jar and files? Could u please send me a link with more information?